# Relation is transitive or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let, R be a relation on Natural numbers.
R = {(1,2),(2,1),(3,4)}

This relation is

- not reflexive, as (1,1) is not present in R
- not symmetric, as (3,4) is present, but (4,3) is not present in R

Is R transitive or not?

Can we conclude that (1,2) and (2,1) are present in R, but (1,1) is not present in R, so, R is not transitive?

Is the relation R transitive or not?

Comment: You are right. (1,2) and (2,1) would imply both (1,1) and (2,2) if relation were transitive.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivially not, as you say, $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ in $R$ but $(1,1)$ not.

Comment: That's not "trivially not".  Do you know what trivial means, in mathematcis?